# How to change all file type extensions at a certain location?

Tags: bash

I'm currently using this line to move all files with a .tif extension to another folder location:

```
ROBOCOPY "H:\Location\User\Test Folder 1" "H:\Location\User\Test Folder 2" *tif /mov
```

Now I want to loop through all the files at `H:\Location\User\Test Folder 2` and convert them from `.tif` to `.pdf` - It looks like the solution might be something like this, but what I don't see here is what folder location this script would be running on (and thusly I'm afraid to test it on my environment) - how do I specify for this to run only on files at `H:\Location\User\Test Folder 2`?

```
for f in *.tif; do 
    mv -- "$f" "${f%.tif}.pdf"
done
```

Comment: You can always do an `echo` before the `mv` command to see if the files are renamed as expected and later remove it

Comment: use the command `cd` for located the directory or simply execute the script from this directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*.tif` glob will only find files in the current working directory.  Thus, you can change the code this way to ensure that it only modifies files in the intended directory:

```
cd "H:\Location\User\Test Folder 2" 
for f in *.tif; do 
    mv -- "$f" "${f%.tif}.pdf"
done
```

Comment: A caveat:   You should run the `cd "H:\Location\User\Test Folder 2" ` command first by copying and pasting out of your script.   This makes sure that if the command fails, you don't accidentally modify files in your current direcgtory.